# Why i am not accesing reset passsword URL before login can you tell me how i access

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-login

**How i access below urls before login i accessed after login below urls anyone tell me what mistake i doing i dont know please tell me how i solve this bug.but when i click on forgot password link without login its occure error 302**

```
login template.html
   <a class="m-auto" href="{% url 'reset_password' %}">Forgot password</a>

urls.py
path('reset_password/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset.html"),
     name="reset_password"),

    path('reset_password_sent/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_sent.html"), 
        name="password_reset_done"),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_form.html"), 
     name="password_reset_confirm"),

    path('reset_password_complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_done.html"), 
        name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? It sounds like you want to make sure these specific views are accessible to non-logged-in users but currently they are not.

Comment: @DHerls my problem is i want perform forgot password which is exist in login template means when anyone click on forgot password link he or she redirect on resetpassword template but i could not do without login means i am logged in and after i go this url  i redirect done on resetpass template  i want access without login